# guard authentication login problem in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using guard for multiple. everything is ok . such as moden controller table . but when I login then show this message `"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'jolbihongo.app\models\account' doesn't exist"`
I can not find problem where any one help me how can solve this problem.

middleware logic code .

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Auth::guard('account')->check()){
       return redirect('accountadminlogin');     
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

login code

```
public function accountlogin(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
     ]);

    if (!Auth::guard('account')->attempt(['email' =>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password])){
        return redirect('/account');
    }
    else{
        Session::flash(' message', 'Your Username Or password Wrong');
    }
}
```

guard login code

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'account' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'accounts',
    ],

    'Maintain' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'maintains',
    ],
],
```

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'accounts' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
       'table' => App\Models\Account::class,
     ],
     
     'maintains' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
       'table' => App\Models\Maintain::class,
     ],
],
```

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],

    'accounts' => [
        'provider' => 'accounts',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],

    'maintains' => [
        'provider' => 'maintains',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

i check my model but its working well only in guard authentication it not found

Comment: in your configuration you are trying to use the `database` driver for your 'accounts' provider. this driver takes a table name, not a Model (since it doesn't use Eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Your `accounts` and `maintains` providers are set to use the `database` driver:

```
'driver' => 'database',
```

This driver takes a table name not a Model class name:

```
'table' => 'accounts',
```

If you check a default `config/auth.php` file you will see an example of using the `eloquent` and `database` driver and the different configurations they use:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```